# How to get values in a dictionary-like string and sort the output all within the column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to analyze the data - https://www.kaggle.com/tmdb/tmdb-movie-metadata?select=tmdb_5000_movies.csv

There is a column in a dataset (genres) that look like a following:

```
d = {'genres' : [[{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 10749, "name": "Romance"}], [], [{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 10749, "name": "Romance"}, {"id": 10769, "name": "Foreign"}]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

so I want the output names of the genres of the movies in the alphabetically sorted order

```
d_output = {'genres': [['Comedy', 'Romance'], [], ['Comedy', 'Foreign', 'Romance']]}

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data=d_output)
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is the easy way to go:

```
pd.DataFrame({'genres':[sorted([x['name'] for x in y]) for y in df['genres']]})
```

Output:

```
                       genres
0           [Comedy, Romance]
1                          []
2  [Comedy, Foreign, Romance]
```

---

**Update**: I didn't notice that your data was stored as `csv` so `genres` is string-type, not lists as in your sample data. In which case:

```
df.genres.str.extractall('"name": "(\w+)"').sort_values([0]).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

output:

```
                            0
0           [Comedy, Romance]
2  [Comedy, Foreign, Romance]
```

Comment: This does not order the genres alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

here's a another nice list comprehension that returns the alphabetically sorted list

```
names = sorted([i['name'] for chunk in d["genres"] for i in chunk])
```

output:

```
['Comedy', 'Comedy', 'Foreign', 'Romance', 'Romance']
```

---

doing this and removing duplicates:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

names = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sorted([i['name'] for chunk in d["genres"] for i in chunk])))
print(names)
```

output:

```
['Comedy', 'Foreign', 'Romance']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have python dict objects serialized as texts in a `csv` file and read again into the data frame, you'd have something like this:

> d = '''{'genres' : [[{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 10749,
> "name": "Romance"}], [], [{"id": 35, "name": "Comedy"}, {"id": 10749,
> "name": "Romance"}, {"id": 10769, "name": "Foreign"}]]}'''
>
> df = pd.DataFrame({'genres': [d]})

You can parse the string itself using regular expressions, as @Quang Hoang suggested. I personally believe that could be bug-prone (or in the very least, less readable), though elegant

With the assumption that you have valid python dicts, you can use

```
import ast
df['genres'] = df.genres.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

To have the serialized string be parsed back as a python dictionary. You could alternatively use the `json` module, if the object is also valid json.

And then continue with the list comprehension normally.